# Why does my laravel project display @extends, @yield and @section as plain text?

Tags: php, laravel, layout, laravel-blade

I created a new laravel project and it displays @extends, @yield and @section as plain text, I have php installed on laragon and everything works fine.

This is my main layout file master.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('src/css/app.css') }}">

    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
@include('partials.header')
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the index.blade.php which is the main part of the project

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Laravel Shopping Cart
@endsection
```

And it just displays [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLjZ5.png)

I dont understand why they dont work alsou my api.php

has this code added for it to work

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('shop.index');
});
```

Comment: How does normal PHP code look like. e.g. `<?php echo 'PHP code'; ?>` ?

Comment: @apokryfos Just like normal code, ![like this](https://i.gyazo.com/d8d55d54f79680c9ce85dbb9ff088d08.png).

Comment: check the folders/files permissions

Comment: I have given full control to all files in that www/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in `@extends ('layouts.master')`.

Comment: That didnt help

Answer (score 0):

you mistake a few  line, 
remove space on this code

**@extends('layouts.master')**

and  make sure your folder position resource->view->shop->index.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

I hadnt run the `php artisan serve` on my project folder, that was causing the issue, thank you to everyone though!!